# FreeRTOS Posix GCC Simulator vTaskDelay doesn't delay properly

Tags: freertos

I am playing with FreeRTOS Posix GCC Simulator and creating simple task and delaying 1 sec and printing just doesn't give right results.
Creating task like this should show text being printed every 1 sec but it seems that it is more like 8-9 sec between prints.
What could be the issue?

```
void prvTask1( void *pvParameters )
{

    for ( ;; )
    {
        printf( "Task 1 ...%d\n", xTaskGetTickCount());

        vTaskDelay( 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS );
    }
}
```

Config:

```
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ              ( ( portTickType ) 1000 )
#define portTICK_RATE_MS                ( ( portTickType ) 1000 / configTICK_RATE_HZ )
```

I've tested with values:

```
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ              ( ( portTickType ) 250)
#define portTICK_RATE_MS                ( ( portTickType ) 1000 / configTICK_RATE_HZ )
```

It looks like it is ~1 sec per printf. Somehow it seems raising values from ~500 > 1000 gives worser results on 1 sec delay (becomes much more then 1 sec).

Comment: What is the value for configuration parameter portTICK_RATE_MS ? I suspect this is not configured properly. Copying the output would be useful.

Comment: Output doesn't provide any info because error is in timing, output values itself are correct.

Answer (score 0):

**FreeRtos** demo **FreeRtosConfig.h** says:

```
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ  ( 1000 )     
// In this non-real time simulated environment 
// the tick frequency has to be at least a multiple 
// of the Win32 tick frequency, and therefore very slow.
```

Maybe you should try to build and run the original example of FreeRtos. 
I did try to run the example of FreeRtos8.2.1 and **vTaskDelay** works just fine